# sns.distplot is plotting negative values for a only positive variable

Tags: python-3.x, plot, seaborn

Hello, I'm trying to plot the distribution of a variable in Python using the sns.distplot function.

For example, I create variable x as a random variable, with only positive values.

```
import pandas as pd
x = np.random.random(100)
```

I then use the sns.distplot function and I get the following graph:
[image]

As you'll be able to see, it looks like there are negative values (-0.25). I check if there are negative values by doing the following:

```
x < 0
>>> array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],       dtype=bool)
```

I don't understand why x seems to have negative values in the plot. Does anyone knows why this is happening? I tried to look if I found more specifications about the sns.ditplot function, but I couldn't find anything that enlightened me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

As you can see the plot only has values from zero. If you do not want to see the negative value in the plot you can set the xlim parameter.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

x = np.random.random(100)
%matplotlib inline
sns.distplot(x).set(xlim=(0))
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gayatri for your reply. I also tried setting a limit to the x-axis, but the shape of the plot is still weird, since it seems that it is "hiding" data. My question is more conceptual in the sense that I don't understand why it seems to have negative observations when in fact I know there aren't. Do you have any idea about how the sns.distplot function is built and why it shows the distribution like this?

Comment: Got it. I think that is how KDE works. Even for positive values the outcome from KDE might be negative. Check this link https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109549/negative-density-for-non-negative-variables. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html#kernel-density-estimation-pitfalls) you can also use the `cut` parameter and set it to 0. So your function call will look like:

```
sns.distplot(x, cut=0)
```